# How to prevent the computation of this polynomial sum?

Tags: polynomials, summation

In my research project, I'm working with the following polynomial
$$p(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \ldots + nx^{n-1} + nx^n + nx^{n+1} + (n-1)x^{n+2} + (n-2)x^{n+3} + \ldots + 2x^{2n-1} + x^{2n}$$
or
$$nx^n +\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+1)x^{2n-i}+(i+1)x^i.$$
Now I would like this to be recognized as a polynomial by Mathematica, so I tried expanding it out with
`Expand[Sum[(i + 1) x^(2 n - i) + (i + 1) x^i, {i, 0, n - 1}] + n x^n]`. That, however, computes the actual sum of the series, and it is no longer a polynomial.

So how do I make Mathematica just treat the sum "as is" so it is recognized as a polynomial? (Ultimately, I'm trying to determine if $p$ has roots of multiplicity $> 1$.)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What output do you expect to get? Does `Total@Table[(i + 1) x^(2 n - i) + (i + 1) x^i, {i, 0, n - 1}] + n x^n` do what you expect for any integer n>0?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear — I use Mathematica very infrequently. I just want the polynomial above to "stay" a polynomial. I do not want Mathematica to evaluate it into a closed form result because after that I wish to take the resultant of $p$ and its reciprocal polynomial $p'$. The command you suggested returns an iterator does not have appropriate bounds error.

Comment: Again, **exactly** what output do you expect to get? For any **specific** integer n>0 the code I gave produces a polynomial expression in x. Does using `Defer[]` help? As in `Defer@Sum[(i + 1) x^(2 n - i) + (i + 1) x^i, {i, 0, n - 1}] + n x^n`?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it much better, but can I just keep $p$ as $p(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \ldots + nx^{n-1} + nx^n + nx^{n+1} + (n-1)x^{n+2} + (n-2)x^{n+3} + \ldots + 2x^{2n-1} + x^{2n}$ and not simplify it into the ugly thing it spits out now? The command you gave certainly works for explicit values of $n$, but I do not wish to plug in values of $n$. Edit: Just saw your edit, let me see if it does what I want!

Comment: Well, `...` is not a Mathematica expression. If that is what you want, then no Computer Algebra System can help you with this.

Comment: Uhm, I know and unfortunately that is not exactly what I want. Again, I apologize because I really seldom use Mathematica or any CAS and am pretty bad at explaining things. What I'm running is this (now with your suggestion) ```poly[x_] = Defer@Sum[(i + 1) x^(2 n - i) + (i + 1) x^i, {i, 0, n - 1}] + n x^n
// q = poly'[x]
// Resultant[poly[x], q, x]``` and when I run that it tells me that $p$ is not a well-formed polynomial in $x$.

Comment: That is because (I think) $p$ is getting computed and simplified into that rational expression thing halfway through. If I can stop Mathematica from simplifying it, then I can get the resultant.

Comment: Your problem is that what you want is impossible. For example, try `Resultant[x^n-1,x-1,x]`. This is impossible because `x^n-1` is **not** an actual polynomial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147146/discussion-between-somos-and-wol).

Comment: Why not use `Together` insteade of `Expand`, and look at roots of the numerator?

Comment: It seems that when `n` is even, `-1` is a repeated root, and otherwise there are no repeated roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about a polynomial

```
p[n_] := n*x^n + Sum[ (i+1)*x^(2*n-i) + (i+1)*x^i, {i, 0, n-1}];
Factor[p[n]]
(* ((-1 + x^n)*(-1 + x^(2 + n)))/(-1 + x)^2 *)
```

which Mathematica is able to partially factor.

For any integer $\,n>0\,$ the polynomial $\,x^n-1\,$ has $\,n\,$
roots being all the $n$-th roots of unity. Thus it factors into
$\,n\,$ linear factors, one for each $n$-th root of unity.

If $\,n>0\,$ is an integer then $\,x-1\,$ is a factor of $\,x^n-1\,$
because $1$ is a $n$-th root of unity. If $\,n>0\,$ is an even integer
then $\,x+1\,$ is also a factor because $-1$ is also a $n$-th root of
unity. In both cases, all other factors are complex conjugate pairs.

Now we define the polynomial
$$ p_n := \frac{(x^n-1)(x^{n+2}-1)}{(x-1)^2}. $$
If $\,n>0 \,$ is even, then $\,n+2\,$ is also even which implies that
$\,(x+1)^2\,$ is a factor of $\,p_n.\,$ If $\,n>0\,$ is odd, then
$\,p_n\,$ has no real factors, only complex conjugate factors.

Your ultimate question

> (Ultimately, I'm trying to determine if p has roots of multiplicity >1.)

has the answer yes if and only if $n$ is even.

Your penultimate question

> So how do I make Mathematica just treat the sum "as is" so it is recognized as a polynomial?

is not possible. For example, you may think that `x^n-1` and
`x^n+1` are both polynomials and therefore you could try to
evaluate `Resultant[x^n+1,x^n-1,x]`. The error message you get

`... Resultant::poly2: 1+x^n is not a well-formed polynomial in x.`

is because a polynomial in x for this purpose must have a degree
which evaluates to an explicit integer and `n` is a symbol with no
value and does not evaluate to an explicit integer.

What does work is something such as

```
Resultant[x^3 + b, x^2 + a, x]
(* a^3 + b^2 *)
```

Answer (score -1):

The automatic Simplify is using the trivial school algebra formula

```
     Sum[x^i,{i,0,n}]== (x^(n+1)-1)/(x-1)
     Sum[(i+1)x^i ,{i,0,n} ] == D[Sum[x^(i+1),{i,0,n}],x]
```

and represents it in the shortest form.

Your first term may stay evaluated but un-simplified for any integer n as

```
   p[x_, n_] :=Append[ Plus @@ Array[ # x^# &, n],\[Ellipsis]]

   p[x, 3]
```

$$ x+  2 x^2 + 3 x^3 +\ldots$$

Here the dots prevent evaluations. You can freeze expressions in a preferred form  by Inactivate for manipulations or by HoldForm for printing purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not really answer the question asked, but nice try.

Comment: Fortuntely, such  questions about trying to prevent a CAS doing its job, demand some fantasy.